# Primary key Foreign key relationship

Tags: sql

I am creating a database where an employer matches a student to a job. I am having trouble with the keys. I figured JobId would probably be the foreign key between these but what would be the foreign key? What relationships should these tables have in common as far as a primary key and foreign key?

here is a pic

[image]

Comment: Which tables do you mean by "between these"?

Comment: I can't read anything in your picture. And please be more explicit in your explanation.

Comment: Is the JobID column the primary on the EmployerJobAnnouncement table? If so then it would not make sense to have the EmployerID in that table since job announcements are usually only tied to 1 employer. Well I never seen a specific job be posted by multiple employers. The JobID in the EmployerParticipant table will handle multiple job announcements per employer if you made the JobID in the EmployerParticipant the foreign key that points to the EmployerJobAnnouncement's JobID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Assuming:

- An employer matches (multiple) students to (one) job
- An employer can have multiple jobs
- A student can apply for multiple jobs

## You should set the keys like so:

1. Table: EmployerPart...

   - PK: EmployerID
   - FK: JobID
2. Table: EmployerJob...

   - PK: JobID
   - FK: EmployerID
3. Table: StudentApp...

   - PK: JobID
   - FK: StudentID
4. Table: Student Part...

   - PK: StudentID
   - FK: JobID